# How to programmatically detect when a device raises an interrupt?

Tags: linux, devices, signals, interrupt

How to programmatically detect when a device raises an interrupt? This can be when a device is connected or disconnected.

And also this case: for example: when a finger is held over a fingerprint scanner, an interrupt is raised. How to detect and possibly trap this interrupt?

I want to write an application using Gtkmm such that when an event occurs like a CD being inserted or a pendrive being plugged in, I catch the interrupt these devices raises and use it to do something in my application, involving these devices.

If it cannot be done in Gtkmm, can I trap the Interrupt at a lower level and inform the Gtkmm application?

I was checking out how GParted behaves. It was initially showing `/dev/sda` and when I connected my pendrive, it automatically opened `files` application. When I checked GParted, pendrive was not present in the drop down menu of devices. It appeared only when I selected “Refresh Devices” in the GParted menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: There's no `gtkmm` tag because questions about that belong on Stack Overflow.  However, the GTK library doesn't include this kind of functionality, and outside of that there's no callback you can register with the system either.

Comment: @goldilocks, should I delete this question and ask the same on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You could, although since as I've said there's no such functionality available in GTK or any other C or C++ library, the question is really, "How can I detect programmatically when a device has been plugged in?", which is okay here.  I'll have a partial answer for you in a minute.

Comment: @goldilocks, ok, I will change the question to what you suggested

Comment: This is a partial answer as it only answers detecting when a device is connected or disconnected. I found a related question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/49092/how-can-i-programmatically-react-to-folder-changes). So using **Inotify** and monitoring the files mentioned by **goldilocks** will work for filesystem changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can try to trap the Interrupt at a lower level and inform the gtkmm application.

No, that is a [kernel space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_space#KERNEL) activity.  Fortunately, the kernel does report the outcome of certain events via interfaces accessible from userland.

It's a little ambiguous in your question whether you want to detect when a block device is attached, or when a filesystem is mounted (although it seems to be more the former).  If your system uses automounting (they usually do by default), it will mount filesystems from block devices when they are attached, otherwise you have to do it manually (e.g., with `mount`).

Either way, you want to poll/parse/scan a kernel **file node** based interface.  I've done this before in an application (a C++ GTK one, in fact) that tracks both attached block devices and mounted filesystems via `/dev/` and `/etc/mtab`.  This is a straightforward, language agnostic method.  Some people find it a little distasteful at first because it involves reading files/directories, but these interfaces do not actually exist on disk, so there is no heavy I/O overhead, and remember: `read()` is a system call.  Reading the file nodes in kernel interfaces amounts to the same thing as a `listAttachedDevices()` style API, except again, it is language agnostic.  When you go to read from these nodes, the kernel passes you the information they represent directly.

The `/dev` directory lists attached devices as special device node files -- e.g. `/dev/sda`.  These are added and removed by the kernel as devices are plugged in and out, so if you track it by polling at intervals (say every 5 seconds), you can detect what's new and what's gone.  The only complication here is that since there's no callback style API, you have to create your own thread for this if you do want a continuous check (perhaps why `gparted` requires you to click `Refresh Devices` instead).

A probably better alternative to `/dev` would be the stuff in `/sys/block`.  Note that there is a significant difference between `/dev` and `/proc` (see below) or `/sys`  in so far as the nodes in the latter contain *information about* things such as devices, whereas the nodes in `/dev` are an *actual connection to the device* (so if you scan `/dev`, don't bother reading the individual files, just note they exist).

`/etc/mtab` now-a-days is a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) (see also the `-s` switch in `man ln`) to `/proc/self/mounts`; `/proc` is a major swiss army knife kernel interface (see `man proc`).  This lists *mounted filesystems*; if you use automounting things will appear and disappear from there when stuff is plugged in/out.  The information in `/proc` and `/sys` is usually in the form of ASCII text, so you can look at these files with `cat`, etc, and parse it with string(stream) functions.

WRT to other kinds of devices, such as a fingerprint scanner, `/sys` is a good place to start -- `/sys/dev` contains a `block` and a `char` directory.  Block devices are usually storage; the information on them can be [randomly accessed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access).  Char devices exchange information with the system in a stream, which would include things like scanners, cameras, HID stuff (human interface device, e.g. mice and keyboards).  I notice that gtkmm does have [some high level stuff](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1DeviceManager.html#details) for attached HID things, presumably since these are significant in interacting with the GUI.

Comment: thanks a lot. A few things went over my head :). Need to read about those in a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I approve of the answer by `goldilocks`. But instead of using the system call `read` to check for filesystem changes, one can use `inotify`.

Its man page is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

There is an excellent explanation and example by the creators (developers) of `inotify` [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478).